# Can I ask about translation works?

Tags: discussion, editing

Since [the help page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) contains

> ***Questions on these topics are welcome here:***
>
> [...]
>
> - The publishing and editing process itself.

I was wondering whether I can ask about this process as regards a *translation* rather than an original writing.

More specifically, I'm interested in asking question(s) about the process. I mean, should I contact the editor of the book in the orginal language? Or an editor of the target language? Maybe the editor of other books from the same author which have already been translated to the target language? Is there a community (I'm not referring to StackExchange communities) that helps "normal people" like me (I mean, non-professional writers) get effectively in touch with appropriate people? And so on.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail as to what you'd be asking? We have a translation tag, and here's an example of a well received question: [Translating analogies in a 100 year old fairy tale](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/60840/34330)

Comment: @Laurel, I've added the info you request, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still relatively new here and definitely can't speak for the community as a whole, so don't take this for an authoritative answer or anything. But here's what I think:

Questions about publishing a wide range of texts are appropriate on Writing SE - fiction, academic, self-publishing, and so on. I don't see why publishing translated works wouldn't belong to that bunch, too.

I'm also not aware of another SE site where such a question would fit.

So I really think that questions about publishing process of translated written works **do** belong on Writing SE.

I might be wrong, but I'm guessing worst case, your question will get migrated and I'll learn that others disagree.

As an aside, let me just note here that questions about the translation itself might better fit to sites dealing with the particular language, or fall under the rule of "don't ask us to rephrase your sentences for you".